# T-SQL Skipping corrupt CSV load statements?

Tags: sql, t-sql, corrupt, openrowset

I currently have a script that loads data from several files into a temp table using OPENROWSET.   Occasionally I am faced with a corrupt file and would like the script to continue if this is found instead of fail.
Example:

```
 SELECT
 CAST(F1 as datetime)               as imported_at
, CAST(F2 as nvarchar(255))         as updated
, CAST(F3 as datetime)              as updated_at
, CAST(F4 as nvarchar(255))         as update_file
  INTO Temp
  FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Excel8.0;HDR=NO;Database=C:\Users\Administrator.WIN-T1K614N8PK3.001\Desktop\TV\file.xlsx','select * from [Tabelle1$]')

  SELECT
  CAST(F1 as datetime)              as imported_at
, CAST(F2 as nvarchar(255))         as updated
, CAST(F3 as datetime)              as updated_at
, CAST(F4 as nvarchar(255))         as update_file
  INTO Temp1
  FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Excel8.0;HDR=NO;Database=C:\Users\Administrator.WIN-T1K614N8PK3.001\Desktop\TV\file1.xlsx','select * from [Tabelle1$]')
```

If the first file cannot open because it is corrupt, I want the script to continue.

Thanks for advice!

Comment: You must use try catch blocks

Answer (score 0):

Try using try/cath blocks...

```
begin try
 SELECT
 CAST(F1 as datetime)               as imported_at
, CAST(F2 as nvarchar(255))         as updated
, CAST(F3 as datetime)              as updated_at
, CAST(F4 as nvarchar(255))         as update_file
  INTO Temp
  FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Excel8.0;HDR=NO;Database=C:\Users\Administrator.WIN-T1K614N8PK3.001\Desktop\TV\file.xlsx','select * from [Tabelle1$]')
end try
begin catch
end catch

begin try
  SELECT
  CAST(F1 as datetime)              as imported_at
, CAST(F2 as nvarchar(255))         as updated
, CAST(F3 as datetime)              as updated_at
, CAST(F4 as nvarchar(255))         as update_file
  INTO Temp1
  FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Excel8.0;HDR=NO;Database=C:\Users\Administrator.WIN-T1K614N8PK3.001\Desktop\TV\file1.xlsx','select * from [Tabelle1$]')
end try
begin catch
end catch
```